# Using Javascript to 'click' a link

Tags: javascript, macos

I am using Safari on the latest version of MacOS (12.3)

I am new to Jacascript and am poking around to learn some things. I am trying to activate a link on a webpage. To determine the button id I right clicked on the link and clicked inspect element. The highlighted element is as follows:

`<a href=​"javascript:​IDS_LinkButtonClick('M$layout$content$PCDZ$MXWGDOM$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl01', "", false, false, false, '', 0, '', '')​;​">​long term​</a>​ = $0`

I *think* the button id is 'M$layout$content$PCDZ$MXWGDOM$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl01'

Using the shortcuts app I made a one action shortcut using the action "Run Javascript On Active Safari Tab"

the code inside is:

`document.getElementById('M$layout$content$PCDZ$MXWGDOM$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl01').click();`
`completion(result);`

Running this action yields the error "unable to run javascript on webpage please ensure the allow java script from apple events is enabled in the develop menu of safari." I have verified - multiple times - that both allow apple events in develop menu and allow javascript in preferences tab are checked. to be sure the I verified javascript does work by running the default code that comes in the shortcut action which did run:

`var result = [];`

`// Get all links from the page`

`var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a");`

`for (let element of elements) {`

`result.push({`

`"url": element.href,`

`"text": element.innerText`

`});`

`}`

`// Call completion to finish`

`completion(result);`

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.  It must be that my interpretation of the element is wrong and javascript can't run because there is no link with that id but don't know how else to interpret it.
thank you

Comment: That a tag has no `id` attribute and therefore no id. I'm not sure what developer tools Safari has but in chrome or FF, the approach I would use would be to inspect the element, right click it and select the CSS selector for the link. Then use that to write your js in the console, targetting the element by the selector with `querySelectorAll(selector-copied-from-inspect)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the button id is 'M$layout$content$PCDZ$MXWGDOM$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl01'

That is not it. Therefore `document.getElementById('M$layout$content$PCDZ$MXWGDOM$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl01')` yields no element, thus calling `.click()` on it will cause an Error.

Since the `a` directly calls a JS function you can simply just call the same yourself as:

```js
IDS_LinkButtonClick('M$layout$content$PCDZ$MXWGDOM$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl01', "", false, false, false, '', 0, '', '')​;
```

The *unable to run javascript on webpage* issue is a separate one. It may be a bad message due to the missing ID causing a JS issue. If other JS code runs fine you should assume the JS giving the error is wrong.

Best way to test it is to paste it into the console in the Developer tools sidebar. Click "Show JavaScript Console" in the Develop menu to open it.

Comment: The code snippet above has a pesky zero width space somewhere when I copied it. I rewrote the command as follows (ad was required to add a completion request): `IDS_LinkButtonClick('M$layout&content$PCDZ$MXWGDOM$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl101', "", false, false, false, '', 0, '', '');`
`// Call completion to finish`
`completion(result);` But even with that I still get a JS error. I stated in a different comment below that the 'M$layout... identifier is part of a table that DOES have an element id. Anyway that helps?

Answer (score 0):

What you thought was the is is nothing but the
`href` value
Using the second method you wrote you can get the exact element you are looking for

```
// Get all links from the page

var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (let element of elements) {
if(element.href===​"javascript:​IDS_LinkButtonClick('M$layout$content$PCDZ$MXWGDOM$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl01', "", false, false, false, '', 0, '', '')​;​" && element.innerText==="long term"){
   // Do your desired work on the particular element
console.log(element)
}
  }

// Call completion to finish
```

Comment: If I wanted to click/ activate into the link using his method how would I do that? I have found that the link an element within a table and the table has an ID

Comment: If you want to click on the element ```var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (let element of elements) {
if(element.href===​"javascript:​IDS_LinkButtonClick('M$layout$content$PCDZ$MXWGDOM$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl01', "", false, false, false, '', 0, '', '')​;​" && element.innerText==="long term"){
   element.click()
}
  }
```

Comment: If the link is the only link in the table use this ** var link=document.querySelector(' #table-id a')   link.click() ** substitute the table-id with your id

Comment: it is not the only link in the table. ...can you loop through table elements and interact with them? Thank you for your help, this is my first foray into JS. I have been using Visual Basic in excel

Comment: Yeah of cause using my first method but changing the ``` var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#table-id a") ``` then running All the other part of that code . If my answer was useful to you don't forget to upvote it

Comment: certainly can give the up vote (it won't record I myself don't have a high enough reputation). I am getting a unexpected string literal error ", false, false, false, '', 0 '', ''):" expected ) to end an if condition

Comment: This should work perfectly ```for (let element of elements) {
if(element.href==`javascript:​IDS_LinkButtonClick('M$layout$content$PCDZ$MXWGDOM$ctl00$Accounts$ctl02$ctl01', "", false, false, false, '', 0, '', '')​;​` && element.innerText=="long term"){
   // Do your desired work on the particular element
console.log(element)
}
  }``` notice :- I changed the number of equals to two and I changed the ```element.href=" "  ```  to  ```element.href=` ` ```

Comment: hmm that gave the original allow apple events error. I might try working something else and coming back to this. thank you for your help